# How to modify particular value from the list of dataframes?

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 data frames representing the point for A and B with columns as X,Y,Z. Now, I have created a list(points_list) of the list(points). Each index in the list consists of 2 data frames.
Now, when I try to modify the value of the X[0] value of point A from the element in the list()points_list). I also modify the values of X value from point B too.

```
point = pd.DataFrame(data ={'X': [0]*2, 'Y': [0]*2, 'Z': [0]*2})

points = []
points_list = []
points.append(point) # for A
points.append(point) # for B  
points_list.append(points)
points_list.append(points)

points_list[0][0].X[0] = 10
print(points_list[0][0].X[0]) # gives 10
print(points_list[1][0].X[0]) # gives 10 which I want to avoid
```

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `points` in `point_list` refer to the same location in memory. Make a `deepcopy` of `points` and then append to `points_list`.

```
>>> import copy
>>> points_list.append(points)
>>> points_list.append(copy.deepcopy(points)) # --> this line is modified
>>> points_list[0][0].X[0] = 10
>>> print(points_list[0][0].X[0]) # gives 10
10
>>> print(points_list[1][0].X[0]) # --> is not 10 anymore
0
```

and continue with the rest.